# Control Android TV using Android app with wifi

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I am not able to discover the android tv in my local network using wifi and pair it with android tv using android code.

I tried to use Network Discovery Service (NDS) in this ip address and port not coming.

End event to send for tv like d-pad and Power off.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.